# CU22 installation on Distributed Always ON - SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, clustering

We're planniing to install SQL 2017 - CU22 on Distributed Always On environment **without taking any downtime**. Can you please review below steps and confirm if need to follow any additional steps to **avoid downtime and impact on business**.

DC1:

dc1-db1 (primary)

dc1-db2 (secondary)

WSFC Name: wsfcdc1

DC2:

dc2-db1 (secondary)

dc2-db2 (secondary)

WSFC name: wsfcdc2

dc2:

1. change failover mode to manual on dc2-db1
2. install CU22 on dc2-db1
3. reboot dc2-db1
4. install CU22 on dc2-db2
5. reboot dc2-db2
6. Change failover mode to automatic

dc1:

1. chnage failover mode to manual on dc1-db1
2. install CU22 on dc1-db1
3. reboot dc1-db1
4. install CU22 on dc1-db2
5. reboot dc1-db2
6. perform manual failover from dc1-db2 to dc1-db1
7. Change failover mode to automatic

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding one more point: Currently application is using DC1-VIP (Listener) to connect DC1 DB.

Please review above steps and confirm to proceed with CU22 installation without any downtime.